# MATLAB vs Numpy multiplication issue

Tags: matlab, numpy

I am trying to get the following MATLAB result in Python/Numpy.

MATLAB Code:

```
A = reshape(ones(1, 12), 3,1,4);
B = reshape(ones(3, 1));
size(A .* B) % ans = 3     1     4
```

Numpy Code:

```
A = np.ones(12).reshape((3,1,4))
B = np.ones(3).reshape((3,1))
(A * B).shape # (3, 3, 4)
```

Question:

How do I change Numpy code to get a result similar to MATLAB's?

Comment: Use `A * B[...,None]`. Or reshape `B` to `(3,1,1)`. More info - https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/user/basics.broadcasting.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In MATLAB the last dimension is the outer one.  Clearly that (3,1) is expanded in that direction to match the (3,1,4) of the other.

In `numpy` the leading dimension is the outer one.  (3,1) broadcasts to (1,3,1), and together with the (3,1,4), the 1's expand to a joint (3,3,4).

To expand in the other direction you need to be explicit, `b[:,:,np.newaxis])`.  Now you have a (3,1,1) that broadcasts with the (3,1,4).

As a historical note, MATLAB originally was strictly 2d, in Fortran, column major form.  Around version 3.5 they allowed higher dimensions, though I believe in a kind of fudged fashion (mapping the last dimensions onto the second).  It readily adds or contracts those last dimensions.  Broadcasting the `numpy` sense is an even newer addition, but with MATLAB specific rules.